# How to prove $E[Z^k]=0$ for all odd values of $k$ when $Z$ is a standard normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, moments

If Z has a standard normal distribution show that $E[Z^k] = 0$ for all odd values of k.

What steps and tools do I need to approach this question, and how to derive it?

Comment: Is that $E[Z^k]$?

Comment: Graph the function $z\to z^k\phi(z)$ (where $\phi$ is the standard Normal pdf) around both sides of $0:$ your eyes will *show* you the area.

Answer (score 1):

Try to calculate
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^k f(z)dz$$
not by integrating directly but making use of [even/odd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) functions. Note that $f(z)$ is $$f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}$$

Comment: I was mainly looking for the solution

Comment: I've just give you a good hint, and didn't share the full solution because it seems like a `self-study` question.